# How to solve the parameters in a multi-function combined integral using R?

Tags: r, gaussian, integral

The total function is an integral :

```
C(x)=∫ R(x-t)*G(t)dt, (lower=0,upper=∞)
```

R(x-t) is a time series,

```
R<-function(t,x){(x-t)*0.0005782559-0.1619717}
```

G(t) is an inverse-Gaussian distribution on time

```
G<-function(t) {sqrt(a^3/(4*pi*b^2*t^3))*exp((-a*(t-a)^2)/(4*b^2*t))}

#where a is the mean age, b is the width
a=integrate(t*G(t),0,Inf)$value
b=sqrt(integrate((t-a)^2*G(t)),0,Inf)$value/2)
```

Now if x=2012, C(x)=269.64, t=25, assume ratio b/a=1, how can I solve the parameters "a" and "b" values to constrain the inverse Gaussian distribution?

What I have tried here:

```
> G<-function(t,a,b=a){
   a<-integrate(G(t,a,b)*t,0,Inf)$value
   b<-sqrt(integrate((t-a)^2*G(t,a,b),0,Inf)$value/2)
   sqrt(a^3/(4*pi*b^2*t^3))*exp((-a*(t-a)^2)/(4*b^2*t))
   }
> C<-function(y,t){(y-t)*0.0005782559-0.1619717}
> g <- Vectorize(function(a) integrate(function(t) G(t=25,a,b=a)*C(y=2012,t=25),lower=0,upper=Inf)$value-269.64)
> uniroot(g,c(.01,500))$root
```

then R will tell an error message

```
Error: C stack usage  15927808 is too close to the limit
```

Comment: Your functions have errors, so I can't run your code, but you may be looking for `uniroot`, which finds the parameter values at which a function is zero (e.g., `total() - 269.64`).

Comment: Thanks for help, I just edited the code and tried `uniroot`, still, it does not work for me.  I try to post it more clearly here, could you help look and check again? Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe your problem formulation is correct. Start with `R(t,x)`. It has a maximum of 1.001479 for `x=2012`, which occurs at `t=0`. The inverse Gaussian PDF (`G(t)`) will integrate to 1, so `∫G(t)R(t,2012)dt` will never get as large as 269.64.